# Версии движков V8 в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

1. Напишите версию движка V8, которая используется в Node.js 14.13.0. Пример оформления:
   // здесь ваше решение из одной строки формата X.Y.ABC.DE (где X- E – это цифры)
2. Выясните версию движка V8, которая используется в Node.js 13.2.0. Затем запишите её в нижнем поле для ввода. Пример оформления:
   // поместите здесь решение из одной строки, например, Z.X.ABC.DE-node.MN

Кто разбирается, пожалуйста, подскажите. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score 1):

Есть, например, такие варианты:

1. Скачать подходящую версию с https://nodejs.org/download/release/ и запустить в консоли `node -p process.versions.v8`.
2. Посмотреть в исходниках соответствующих версий (по тегам в GitHub) в этом файле:

   https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v13.2.0/deps/v8/include/v8-version.h

   https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.13.0/deps/v8/include/v8-version.h

   Нужны вот эти строки:

   ```
   #define V8_MAJOR_VERSION 7
   #define V8_MINOR_VERSION 9
   #define V8_BUILD_NUMBER 317
   #define V8_PATCH_LEVEL 23
   ```

   ```
   #define V8_MAJOR_VERSION 8
   #define V8_MINOR_VERSION 4
   #define V8_BUILD_NUMBER 371
   #define V8_PATCH_LEVEL 19
   ```
3. Найти нужную версию в в любом из этих файлов и посмотреть там:

   https://nodejs.org/download/release/index.json

   https://nodejs.org/download/release/index.tab

Что касается суффикса `-node.MN`, это номер нодовских патчей, их можно посмотреть в строке типа `'v8_embedder_string': '-node.20',` в этом файле (тоже по тегам версий в GitHub):

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v13.2.0/common.gypi